# How to po a large char* data in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, po

I have tried to `po` a `char* data`in Xcode when debugging.

But it's just show with "******...", not the fully content.

And I have try `po (size_t)strlen(data)`  it about 1230000, should much bigger then what I have saw when I using `po data`.

What I should do?

Comment: You really want to `po` 12.3 MB? `strlen` only works on null terminated strings, not arbitrary data.

Comment: @Zaph,  it's 1230000bytes, about 1.2M. Actual it's a Json format data. My purpose is to check if the data is correct. Because app is crash when dealing with the data.

Comment: Save the data to a file to see it.

Comment: @Zaph, yes, let me try.